# In King of Tokyo, how does Mecha Blast interact with High Altitude Bombing?

Tags: king-of-tokyo, king-of-tokyo-power-up

King of Tokyo: Powerup has an evolution card for Meka Dragon called Mecha Blast that reads:

> Discard this Evolution to deal 2 extra damage.

There is also a discardable card from the main game called High Altitude Bombing which reads:

> All monsters (including you) take 3 damage.

Can Mecha Blast be played after/during High Altitude Bombing to make it do 5 damage instead of 3 to everyone?

Comment: The answer appears to have a typo, should be "doesn't have to be an attack"

Comment: Here's the actual text for Mecha Blast showing the text is the same. There's nothing on it mentioning an attack. https://cf.geekdo-images.com/images/pic1449040_md.jpg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the card doesn't specify that the damage has to come from you it's not considered an "attack". The rules state

> If a card deals damage when purchased (like Gas Refinery), this is not
>   considered an attack. Monsters cannot yield Tokyo based on this
>   damage, and cards that affect attacks do not affect these cards.

Since the Mecha Blast evolution does not specify that it effects an **attack** and since the rules also state that you can use your evolution cards at any time, then you should be able to add 2 damage to any damage that was dealt. In this case 5 damage would be dealt to everyone, including you.

Keep in mind that you must be alive at the end of your turn in order to win.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily interpret it this way. Seems at least as likely that you could add 2 extra damage to just 1 person, as you are causing damage to each person.

Comment: I'm assuming you meant to say "does not specify that it effects an attack"?

Comment: @Michael yes, I fixed it

Comment: Makes sense - thank you. And yes, I would have been (barely alive) had I pulled off this combo. :)

Comment: I agree with Gendolkari's concern. While the game's effects aren't well-defined, Mecha Blast says to deal 2 extra damage, not to add 2 damage to an effect that's dealing damage. So you pick someone you're dealing damage to, and then you deal 2 extra damage. On the other side of things, if you're attacking, it might be reasonable to apply it to everyone. Ultimately it's a playgroup or game-owner interpretation, due to the lack of official clarification.